# How to respond to 'included' JSPs from Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a `login.jsp` form that I have written for a website that just contains a form for logging in that I can include and re-use in different places.  The first place I am including it is in my `index.jsp` homepage.

I have an HTTPServlet that the form submits to, and if the username/password is invalid the Servlet sends a message back to display to the user, otherwise it forwards them on to their homepage.

My problem is that I want to forward them back to the same page they're on if their details are incorrect, but display the message, but forwarding to the login page displays only that form in the browser, outside of the page it was included in.  Is there any way I can forward back to the current page?  Or is this perhaps not the best way to go about this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try response.sendRedirect("/yourpage.jsp"); or RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourpage.jsp");
        
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: Please clarify: you are including a login.jsp in index.jsp, and you want the servlet to return you to index.jsp if the user login fails to log in? And if you include login.jsp in another page (for example logme.jsp) you want the servlet to return you to that page (logme.jsp) if the login fails?

Comment: You can easily achieve this task using AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming you are using a `<jsp:include>`.  Here is something you might do:

```
<jsp:include page="loginForm.html">
    <jsp:param name="currentPage" value="${whateverTheCurrentPageIs}" />
</jsp:include>
```

Include the `currentPage` variable in the loginForm.  Then, in your servlet, you want to redirect/forward to the URL you passed in that `currentPage` variable.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, and I can access 'currentPage' in login.jsp using request.getParameter("currentPage"); but back at the servlet it's unavailable using the exact same code.  Do I need any additional steps to make sure it gets back to the Servlet?

Comment: Yes.  In the actual login form, you should pass it as hidden input argument.  `<input name="currentPage" value="${currentPage}"/>`  If you don't do this, it will never be passed with the other login information.